# Using Azure Identity credentials for Spark access to Blob store

Tags: apache-spark, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use Azure RBAC to secure access to storage blobs, and to use Azure Identity to access those blobs from Apache Spark. I see that recent versions of Hadoop-Azure support abfs, and it supports a few token providers: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#Azure_Managed_Identity . For production usage, I can use a service principal with an AD app and the associated client id, secret, and endpoint. Or I can even use Managed Identity.

When developing locally, it would be good to be able to do the same with something like DeviceCodeCredential or InteractiveBrowserCredential, i.e. something that will make the user log in to Azure using a browser, and use the credentials returned to get the access token as pass it to Spark. The reason I'd like this is to have users use their own credentials when accessing data, and not have storage keys / SAS tokens / etc flying about.

Is something like this possible? I could implement a Custom Token Provider that wraps an Azure Identity instance, but was wondering if there were a less nuclear approach.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the user credential to auth, the closest way in the [supported auth ways](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#Authentication) is the [`OAuth 2.0: Username and Password`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0:_Username_and_Password), but essentially it uses the [Azure AD ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) to auth, it has some limits, e.g. it will not work with the user account which is MFA-enabled.

Actually, for local development, the way I most want to recommend is to use a service principal to auth i.e. [`OAuth 2.0 Client Credentials`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0_Client_Credentials), because the MSI(managed identity) is essentially a service principal managed by azure, if you use MSI for production, the transition of the environment will be smoother, the permissions stuff in azure will be some differences between the user account and service principal in some scenarios(maybe not in this case). Of course, Custom Token Provider is also a feasible way, they all depend on yourself.

Comment: Thanks... that's what I found out as well. None of them work that well. The biggest blocker seems to be that there's no way of specifying an access token explicitly, only storage keys. And CustomTokenProvider requires quite a bit of setup.

Comment: @ashic i think client credentials will work https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html#OAuth_2.0_Client_Credentials

Comment: Yes, but the issue is I'm looking to use RBAC configured access against the users. So while client credentials will work, they need the client id and secret of an AD app that the relevant user has access to. I'm looking to use DeviceCodeCredential or something similar so the access to storage is directly against the user's account.